# ASP.NET MVC ViewPage Lifecycle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewpage

I would like to know when (which event/function) the class System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage runs when it reads the @Page directive of the view.

In particular, I would like to programmaticly interpret the values of the @Page directive, override them, then have the cycle continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This SO question / answer should help you with what you need:

[What is the 'page lifecycle' of an ASP.NET MVC page, compared to ASP.NET WebForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460145/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-page-compared-to-asp-net-webforms)

Comment: I saw that page. It has me running around in circles, everything is inheriting everything.

I'm looking for the exact method that Parses the @Page directive of the .aspx/.ascx file.