# Page generation time - ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for a way to track how long it took for a page to be generated by the server. I know I can use Trace to track this but I need a way to display this per page.

Its ASP.Net MVC 2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yep the Derin Suggestion is the standard Way to do it in an ASP.NEt application, i would just suggest add an if so it does not interfere with non-HTML responses:
EDIT: added complete implementation

```
public class PerformanceMonitorModule : IHttpModule
{

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Set Page Timer Star
            HttpContext requestContext = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            requestContext.Items["Timer"] = timer;
            timer.Start();
             };
        context.PostRequestHandlerExecute += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            HttpContext httpContext = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
            HttpResponse response = httpContext.Response;
            Stopwatch timer = (Stopwatch)httpContext.Items["Timer"];
            timer.Stop();

            // Don't interfere with non-HTML responses
            if (response.ContentType == "text/html")
            {
                double seconds = (double)timer.ElapsedTicks / Stopwatch.Frequency;
                string result_time = string.Format("{0:F4} sec ", seconds);
                RenderQueriesToResponse(response,result_time);
            }
        };
    }
    void RenderQueriesToResponse(HttpResponse response, string result_time)
    {
        response.Write("<div style=\"margin: 5px; background-color: #FFFF00\"");
        response.Write(string.Format("<b>Page Generated in "+ result_time));
        response.Write("</div>");
    }
    public void Dispose() { /* Not needed */ }
}
```

you can also add some style to it...

And remember to register your Module in WebConfig inside httpModules Section:

```
  <add name="Name" type="namespace, dll"/>
```

For a Complete Reference about this check the Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework by Steven Sanderson - Chapter 15 - Performance, Monitoring Page Generation Times.

EDIT:(comment @Pino)
Here is the example for my project:
[alt text http://www.diarioplus.com/files/pictures/example_performance.JPG](http://www.diarioplus.com/files/pictures/example_performance.JPG)

Comment: Thanks - works well except This seems to output AFTER the </html> element which breaks my page :( suggestions?

Comment: This is added (append) as part of the response, it may not be after the HTML closing tag.

Comment: I edit my post with a sample img, i already have a project running and test it, i don't know why Darin said its after the HTML..?, maybe he referred to another implementation.

Comment: Can you post full example? the code at the moment is displaying below the </html> tag.

Answer (score 16):

You can implement it like a ActionFilterAttribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class LoggingAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly Stopwatch _sw;

    public LoggingAttribute()
    {
        _sw = new Stopwatch();
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        _sw.Start();
        Debug.WriteLine("Beginning executing: " + GetControllerAndActionName(filterContext.ActionDescriptor));
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        _sw.Stop();
        var ms = _sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        Debug.WriteLine("Finishing executing: " + GetControllerAndActionName(filterContext.ActionDescriptor));
        Debug.WriteLine("Time elapsed: "+ TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms).TotalSeconds);
    }

    private string GetControllerAndActionName(ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        return actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName + " - " + actionDescriptor.ActionName;
    }
}
```

Decorate every controller or action-method with it and voila, it spit outs the text in debug.

EDIT: If you want to print it on the page you could add this snippet to the OnActionExecuted method

```
if(filterContext.Result is ViewResult) { //Make sure the request is a ViewResult, ie. a page
  ((ViewResult) filterContext.Result).ViewData["ExecutionTime"] = ms; //Set the viewdata dictionary
}
```

Now you have the executiontime saved in ViewData and can access it in the page.. I usually put it in the masterpage like this

```
<!-- The page took <%= ViewData["ExecutionTime"] %> ms to execute -->
```

Comment: Decorate every controller or action-method is a bit of a pain as we have a lot (Pretty big project) - anyway we can make this work site wide without making such a large change?

Comment: In my projeect all my controllers inherits from a BaseController. So I just decorate the basecontroller, which in turn "decorates" all action-methods being executed.

Comment: Its Pretty good approach, its just worth mentioning that this actually track the Controller life time, and not the total Request life time.

Comment: @Omar, from my understanding a Request begins when an Action is "Executing" and ends when an Action is "Executed". What would be the request life time otherwise?

Comment: @Baddie, probably things like an HttpModule wouldn't be measured. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: @Baddie - Before the Controller get Invoked, there are some other Handlers that take action first (like System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler), here are some good resources about ASP MVC Life cycle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460145/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-page-compared-to-asp-net-webforms/460165#460165.

Comment: @Pino - With ASP.NET MVC3 you can add the attribute to the GlobalFiltersCollection during the `Application_Start` handler to avoid decorating every class/action with it.

Comment: Shouldn't the elapsed time be calculated i OnResultExecuted instead of OnActionExecuted?

Comment: I agree with @BigJoe714

Comment: Or track both? :) Anyways nowadays I just use MvcMiniProfiler which is great!

Answer (score 4):

It will depend on where you want to include this information. For example you could write an http handler that will display the render time after the `</html>` tag:

```
public class RenderTimeModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var watch = new Stopwatch();
            var app = (HttpApplication)sender;
            app.Context.Items["Stopwatch"] = watch;
            watch.Start();
        };

        context.EndRequest += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var app = (HttpApplication)sender;
            var watch = (Stopwatch)app.Context.Items["Stopwatch"];
            watch.Stop();
            var ts = watch.Elapsed;
            string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0} ms", ts.TotalMilliseconds);
            app.Context.Response.Write(elapsedTime);
        };
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

If you want to display render time somewhere in the middle of the html page then this render time will not account for the total page render time.

Comment: This seems to output AFTER the </html> element which breaks my page :( suggestions?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my post. You could put it in a comment if you don't want to break your validation.

Comment: Will this approach work with Json and File results or just html?