# Azure Traffic Manager, Priority Mode: Browser refresh won't go to secondary node when primary goes down

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-traffic-manager

We are testing out Traffic Manager to see if it is a viable solution for failover.  If our primary Azure region becomes unavailable for any reason, we want end users to be directed to a secondary location where they can continue using the site.

I have followed the documentation for setting this up and have 3 simple API return pages as endpoints in 3 different regions that simply alert which one you are hitting.  I have them prioritized, 1, 2 and 3.

When hitting the `.trafficmanager.net` URL, the primary is displayed as it should.  All 3 show "online" in the traffic manager profile.  If I stop the primary site, then refresh my browser, I get a 403 error stating that the site has stopped.

I set the TTL in the traffic manager profile configuration to 60 seconds.  However, after 15+ minutes, the browser still displays the 403.  The only way I seem to be able to get the secondary site to pull up is by starting a new browser session.  It's like there is some sort of caching and/or TTL issue with the browser session that prevents it from trying the secondary site.

This obviously wouldn't be acceptable in a live, production environment.  There has to be a way around this, right?  Has anyone else dealt with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The browser might be using [Keep-Alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)

Keep in mind that Azure Traffic Manager works at the DNS level so, rather than using a browser to get a repro, try to get a repro with some DNS tools like dig, nslookup, etc.

Comment: Thanks for you response.  This does appear to be what is happening.  But this wouldn't be an acceptable failover option for an application that is browser based.  We need a solution in which the end user is unaware there was ever a problem, rather than one where they must be instructed to start a new browser session if the site goes down.  Maybe this is just something that hasn't been implemented by Microsoft yet.  Hopefully they will make some improvements soon.

Comment: Not sure if this falls into Microsoft's domain, but I believe you can disable Keep-Alive wherever you host your website. For example, check out this post on how to do it in ASP.NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975983/how-can-i-disable-http-keep-alive-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

This isn't just a browser setting. Your IIS Manager could be considered to use keep-alive to reduce strain on itself, thus leaving open connections that completely bypass the Traffic Manager's DNS rules. I had these exact same symptoms, and was able to alleviate them by following steps I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43031827/how-do-i-get-azure-traffic-manager-to-work-as-a-failover-for-two-web-apps/45495003#45495003). Whether it'll prove useful in a real-world scenario has yet to be seen, but I'm hoping this will help you get further.