# Azure 2 load balancers in Active/Passive mode

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-load-balancer

On Azure how can I have 2 load balancers in Active/Passive mode, so that if one goes down the other one can become active?

Comment: If the reply is helpful, you could accept it to close this question or let me know if you need further help?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two public-facing load balancers, you could use [Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview) to do failover with two endpoints. That is to add your load balancer public frontend IP address as the endpoint and configure the **routing method** (based on geographic location, priority, weighted, performance, multivalue, subnet) using Traffic Manager. Then if one endpoint goes down, Traffic Manager will direct the traffic to another endpoint.

Traffic Manager works at the DNS level, consider the DNS resolution might fail sometimes. You could read [recommendations for Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/design-principles/redundancy#recommendations).

> Traffic Manager is a possible failure point. Review the Traffic
>   Manager SLA, and determine whether using Traffic Manager alone meets
>   your business requirements for high availability. If not, consider
>   adding another traffic management solution as a failback. If the Azure
>   Traffic Manager service fails, change your CNAME records in DNS to
>   point to the other traffic management service.

For more references, you could read this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211448/is-azure-traffic-manager-is-reliable-for-failover-what-are-other-problems-i-sho).