# Asp.net MVC page life cycle

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the best way to apply a treatment after the page is rendered (view calculated, html helpers calculated, partial views calculated and so on...) but before the response is sent to the client ? In order to modify this response (with DB access needed)...

Thank you

Comment: I can't tell what you want answered. Please try to clear up your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826657/page-generation-time-asp-net-mvc was ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create an [HttpModule](http://sd-interestingone.blogspot.com/2009/01/what-is-httpmodulewhen-and-how-to-write.html) to handle post-processing events

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onresultexecuted.aspx

Comment: FYI, this is called *before* a view is rendered.

Comment: @Dave: No. It's called ***after*** the view have been rendered. You might be thinking on OnActionExecuted.

Comment: Are you certain? I've tested this first hand (mvc-2) and, at least in MVC2, it's called before :(

Comment: Yes I'm sure. And the behavior haven't changed since mvc2. You can read the `ViewResultBase` source code here: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/68345#288022

Comment: :( I'll have to revisit this then, because I'd wanted to teardown some Contextual stuff in the OnResultExecuted, which (definitely) causes a nullException when I access the object I'm looking to teardown from the view at render time... Thanks for the link.

Comment: OnResultExecuted is called for all action results. You need to check that the result contains a view.

Comment: Yep - turns out, I had some mini controller actions, which were doing the teardown - paying some attention to the ChilAction attribute's sorted it. Thanks for the pointer!