# In ASP.NET MVC 3, How can I use OnResultExecuting/OnresultExecuted method to trace the page load time?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I put OnResultExecuting/OnResultExecuted code in my controller and I enabled trace in web.config, but nothing was shown on any of the pages for the controller about the trace information (I just got original page, appending trace.axd does not work either!)

The web.config to enable trace:

```
<system.web><trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/></system.web>
```

OnResultExecuting/OnResultExecuted:

```
protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        string action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        start_time = DateTime.Now;
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(string.Format("Start '{0}/{1}' on: {2}", controller, action, start_time));
    }

    protected override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        string controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        string action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        var elapsed_time = DateTime.Now - start_time;
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(string.Format("Start '{0}/{1}' on: {2}", controller, action, elapsed_time));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know about the mvc mini profiler - http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

It was written by sam saffron who develops this very site.

Sounds like it may already do what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Make an actionfilter instead. I've pasted some code over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826657/page-generation-time-asp-net-mvc/1826882#1826882).

ActionFilters are a lot easier to reuse and can be implemented globally.