# What are some of the must know concepts in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I am giving a small presentation to a group of Java developers and looking for some core areas to target. Ideally I would like to only talk about the core concepts in ASP.NET.

I am coming up with

- Authentication
- Session State
- ASP.NET MVC
- LINQ (more .net)

Any more that I should be considering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most important things to learn is the ASP.net lifecycle. It makes debugging much more worthwhile...

For ASP.net WebForms -

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

[Useful cheat sheet](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/aspnet-life-cycles-events.pdf)

It is important to keep the life cycle in mind when developing web based applications.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is specifically the ASP.Net **WebForms lifecycle**, not a general ASP.Net lifecycle, e.g. the MVC lifecycle is completely different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460145/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-page-compared-to-asp-net-webforms

Answer (score 1):

I'd focus on ASP.NET MVC (because while MVC is bread and butter in Java, that's a pretty cool implementation) and LINQ, especially the runtime query construction you can do with something like PredicateBuilder (because Java can't do that and it's a very good way to demonstrate the unique capabilities of C#).