# Are there events for before a controller is run?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I know there are events for before/after a action is fired.

Is there anything higher up in the stack like before a controller is called?

Comment: outside of the controller, higher up in the stack just before the controller is called.

Comment: If you are trying to figure out which controller is going to be instantiated at run-time, a controllerfactory would help. Hard to say what you mean without an example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 9):

There's no such notion as *running a controller*. Controllers are not run. They are classes which are instantiated and actions (methods) are invoked on them.

You could decorate your controller action with a custom [`[ActionFilter]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx) attribute in which you could override the [OnActionExecuting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onactionexecuting(v=VS.100).aspx) which will be called before the controller action is invoked. This technique also allows you a better separation of concerns.

Answer (score 7):

ASP.Net MVC still runs through the `HttpApplication` pipeline, so you can still handle any of the events from `BeginRequest` through to `PreRequestHandlerExecute` by adding handlers to Global.asax.

Answer (score 2):

Many application lifecycle events can be handled in the [Global.asax file.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following SO question which explain the lifecycle in ASP.NET MVC.

[What is the 'page lifecycle' of an ASP.NET MVC page, compared to ASP.NET WebForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460145/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-page-compared-to-asp-net-webforms)