# migrating webforms to Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, migration, razor

With ASP.NET MVC 3, I am trying to migrate a webform page to a Razor page.

I could not find a way to migrate this kind of code
I used this kind of code in webforms:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
          base.OnInit(e);
          my other code here...
     }
</script>
```

I could not find a way to translate this in Razor.

Answer (score 2):

Because ASP.NET MVC does not have the same "page lifecycle" like Web Forms does (that's a good thing). Have a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460145/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-page-compared-to-asp-net-webforms) to see the comparison of the two.

You can use `_ViewStart.cshtml` for this purpose (will execute before any View renders)

**_ViewStart.cshtml:**

```
@{
    @* Your code here, e.g: *@
    ViewBag.Theme = "MyTheme"
}
```

Comment: My understanding is _ViewStart.cshtml applies to all pages
I have so many pages and each has its own initialization code

Comment: @user385411 - what does the code do? Couldn't it go in the Controller?

Answer (score 0):

How about an Action Filter. Action filters are custom attributes that provide a declarative means to add pre-action and post-action behavior to specific controller action methods. It sounds like that might be what you're looking for.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3