# Asp.Net MVC Life cycle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the 'page lifecycle' of an ASP.NET MVC page, compared to ASP.NET WebForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460145/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-page-compared-to-asp-net-webforms)

I will appreciate if Gurus Out there can point me to ASP.Net MVC Life cycle. I am interested to know what happens once a request comes and a response is sent and where does ControllerFactory comes in picture.
this will help me to understand the hooks and extension point to MVC.
All pointers are appreciated.

P.S. Is there any way I can step into code and see how the Factories are being used to create instance.

Thanks

Comment: Does this similar question not help you? First result on Google for your query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460145/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-page-compared-to-asp-net-webforms

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Steve Sanderson's [Request-Handling Pipeline Poster](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/10/08/aspnet-mvc-learning-resource-request-handling-pipeline-poster/).

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460145/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-page-compared-to-asp-net-webforms) is a pretty good answer. Also [here](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/03/18/asp-net-mvc-in-depth-the-life-of-an-asp-net-mvc-request.aspx) etc. These are just top results on Google for "asp mvc lifecycle," so you can probably find more if you need them.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.beletsky.net/2011/06/inside-aspnet-mvc-route-to-mvchanlder.html) are some  blogposts for quick review