# ASP.Net MVC - Request Life Cycle

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to search the Video of Request Life Cycle of MVC.

I tried a lot on Google, but could not found it.

Comment: Page Life cycle is a WebForm concept not ASp.Net Mvc.

Comment: an overview poster http://code.google.com/p/ufos-tw-internal/downloads/detail?name=asp_net_mvc_poster.pdf

Comment: @shakib - it is asp.net not mvc

Comment: @ihihjkjk As stated in the poster header, it is "ASP.NET MVC: The Request-Handling Pipeline"

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425773/asp-net-mvc-life-cycle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460145/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-page-compared-to-asp-net-webforms  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460145/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-page-compared-to-asp-net-webforms

Answer (score 25):

[image]

Below is the detail explanation of the same.

Step 1 Fill route: - MVC requests are mapped to route tables which in turn specify which controller and action to be invoked. So if the request is the first request the first thing is to fill the route table with routes collection. This filling of route table happens in the global.asax file.

Step 2 Fetch route:- Depending on the URL sent “UrlRoutingModule” searches the route table to create “RouteData” object which has the details of which controller and action to invoke.

Step 3 Request context created: - The “RouteData”  object is used to create the “RequestContext” object.

Step 4 Controller instance created: - This request object is sent to “MvcHandler” instance to create the controller class instance. Once the controller class object is created it calls the “Execute” method of the controller class.

Step 5 Execute Action: - The “ControllerActionInvoker” determines which action to executed and executes the action.

Step 6 Result sent: - The action method executes and creates the type of result which can be a view result , file result , JSON result etc.

So in all there are six broad steps which get executed in MVC request life cycle.

courtesy the above image taken from this codeproject article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/556995/MVC-interview-questions-with-answers

Answer (score 6):

Below is the MVC Life Cycle:

```
- App initalization
- Routing
- Instantiate and execute controller
- Lcate and invoke controller action
- Instantiate and render View
```

Answer (score 4):

[Lifecycle of an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application) - was published a week ago or so.

Here is a PDF file to [download](http://i1.asp.net/media/4773381/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application.pdf?version_id=&cdn_id=2014-02-10-002).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In short.
ASP.NET MVC uses [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) internally. When you see the MapRoute call, it's actually an extension method that will register a specific route to an [MvcRouteHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvcroutehandler%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

This route handler's GetHttpHandler will return a [MvcHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchandler%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) which is able to handle the request that matched the route.e.g. http://yourdomain.com/{controller}/{action}