# How the Request pass from view to controller?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to know the logic behind the request pass from view to controller?how controller understand to which ActionMethod has to invoke for a particular click?"

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX or http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx

Comment: FYI, unless you narrow the scope of your question, this is probably going to end up getting closed for being either too broad or off topic.

Comment: for example @Html.ActionLink("MyLink", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "shadowborder"}), is saying go to the HomeController and do the code under Index, by the way can you add this css for aesthetics. The question is I might agree with valverij a little broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the short anwser -

**Controller factory** -  responsible for creating instances of controllers to service a request

**Action invoker** - responsible for finding and invoking the action method in the controller class.

[image]

If you want to know more details, you want to read [Pro ASP.NET MVC 4 - Controller Extensibility - Chapter 17](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242361).

Answer (score 0):

MVC uses **[Front Controller Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern)**

Refer

[MVC Execution Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381612%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[FrontControllerPattern in MVC](http://packtlib.packtpub.com/library/9781847195500/ch05lvl1sec02)

[MVC Life cycle article](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/TbR0041112-Asp.net-MVC-Request-Life-Cycle.html)

[ASP.Net MVC - Request Life Cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647969/asp-net-mvc-request-life-cycle) 
and [Asp.Net MVC Life cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425773/asp-net-mvc-life-cycle)

and lot more can be found in google. Its already explained in lot of places