# What occurs in the begin request when reviewing glimpse timelines for an MVC4 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, glimpse

I am new to glimpse and new to MVC4.

I am attempting to review timelines throughout my MVC application in order to streamline areas of my application that are possibly taking up too much time.

What I am noticing is that some of my views are showing substantial amounts of time between the Begin Request and Executing: Authorization Filter.  So, my Begin Request starts out at 0ms and has 0 duration, but Executing: Authorization Filter per my example shows starting at 23ms so why the 23ms gap between the two?

The example I have uploaded is no where near as drastic as some of my traces that I have reviewed I have seen one that has a gap between the two mentioned above of 1500ms.

Any ideas on what would cause something like this?

[image]

Comment: I don't know exactly if you are asking about MVC page lifecycle or glimpse trace, if you are interested in the first topic, this post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460145/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-page-compared-to-asp-net-webform

Comment: I read that article previously thank you, I am asking specifically about those two items in the glimpse trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of things can happen between the request beginning and an execution filter being executed.

Glimpse does not show every method and its execution time, for that you'd need a true profiler like [Ants Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/).

I'd recommend using that tool if you want to know all the details, and Glimpse if you just want a lightweight way of seeing what is taking up time in a given request.

Comment: Wish I had the money for ants.  I don't think they will continue to give me evaluation versions.

Comment: You're in luck! They do have a [14 day free trial](http://www.red-gate.com/dynamic/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/download). By the way - they also [support the development of Glimpse](http://blog.getglimpse.com/2012/09/06/were-on-it-full-time/)!

Comment: Yeah I know, I have used the 14 day trial twice already.  That is what I meant regarding the evaluation version.  Marked as answer as I did find the issue using Ants, I happened to have the performance profiler installed but hadn't used it up as I was using the memory profiler for the last trial i downloaded.