# asp.net mvc 4 - Who calls _ViewStart.cshtml and what is the sequence of steps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC so please bear with me. I am trying to find out who calls Viewstart.cshtml and what is the sequence of steps involved there? is it called after the route table is accessed or before it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The RazorViewEngine has an internal readonly field "ViewStartFileName" which specifies the name of the start view. _ViewStart.cshtml (or .vbhtml) is called each time a RazorView instance is rendered (specifically when the RenderView() method is being executed).
So the "who" would be the RazorViewEngine with its corresponding RazorView class (including their base classes). To get a quite good overview on the MVC request pipeline I recommend this [pdf](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/entrypage/be-ahead-of-the-game-poster1).

Comment: Hi  @Andreas Great answer, but I have a question, is it possible to change the name of the "ViewStartFileName" ?

Comment: Where is that PDF now?

Answer (score 10):

Check the image below... ([What is the 'page lifecycle' of an ASP.NET MVC page, compared to ASP.NET WebForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460145/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-page-compared-to-asp-net-webform))

[image]