# Achieving UpdatePanel-Functionality in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, updatepanel

I got a `Label`, a `Textbox` and a `Button` on a `Page`.

When entering a Value into the `Textbox` I want to display something on the `Label`. The `Button` also gets that information and runs some code.

In ASP.NET I would just put an Ajax `UpdatePanel` around those three controls, add two events on `TextBox`. `TextChange` and `Button.Click` and react on Postback.

How do I do this in MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Life cycle of MVC and webforms both are different.
MVC is not about server controls.... viewstate... no page life cycle events in web form...

[What is the 'page lifecycle' of an ASP.NET MVC page, compared to ASP.NET WebForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460145/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-page-compared-to-asp-net-webform)
hope this helps..

Now coming to your point.

if you want to display something in the Label while entering a Value into the Textbox  you have to use client side script see example below

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function textCounter(field, field2, maxlimit) {
            var countfield = document.getElementById(field2);
            if (field.value.length > maxlimit) {
                field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
                return false;
            } else {
                countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
            }
        }
</script>
```

Your Html page

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Account", FormMethod.Post)) // here index is a ActionName, Account is a controller name
      {%>

<input type="text" name="Message"  onkeyup="textCounter(this,'counter',208)"/>

<label><input disabled  maxlength="3" size="3" value="208" id="counter"  /></label>

<input type="submit" value="Send" />  
<%}%>
```

Here
textCounter() function on keyup event in textbox will display value in label,

submit button will submit form, calling action "index" on controller "Account",see below how action act

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult index(FormCollection result)
    {
     string TextBoxValue=result["Message"];
     return view("yourviewname");
     }
}
```

i hope this example may help you..