# ASP.NET : Textbox OnTextChanged MVC refresh whole page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, textbox, autopostback

I'm having a trouble while devolping my .net application.

I'm using the event OnTextChanged on a textbox to change the content in another Textbox, the first textbox has AutoPostBack="true", but when i write in it and click in another part, the page refreshes completely.

here is my ascx code:

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
    Change text
    <asp:TextBox id="txt1" runat="server" ontextchanged="ejemplo" autopostback="true"/>
    <p><asp:Label id="lbl1" runat="server" /></p>
</form>
```

and the script in the same ascx page:

```
<script runat="server">
protected void ejemplo(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbl1.Text = "Changed";
        }
</script>
```

I'm using MVC4,
Thanks for your answers.

**EDIT:**

here is a video of what is really happening:
http://remainedesign.com/video/asd.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Life cycle of MVC and webforms both are different.
MVC is not about server controls.... viewstate... no page life cycle events in web form...

[What is the 'page lifecycle' of an ASP.NET MVC page, compared to ASP.NET WebForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460145/what-is-the-page-lifecycle-of-an-asp-net-mvc-page-compared-to-asp-net-webform)
hope this helps..

Now coming to your point.

if you want to display something in the Textbox2 while entering a Value into the Textbox1  you have to use client side script, see example below

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function textCounter(field, field2, maxlimit) {
            var countfield = document.getElementById(field2);
            if (field.value.length > maxlimit) {
                field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
                return false;
            } else {
                countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
            }
        }
</script>
```

Your Html page

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Account", FormMethod.Post)) // here index is a ActionName, Account is a controller name
      {%>

<input type="text" id="textbox1" name="Message"  onkeyup="textCounter(this,'textbox2',208)"/>

<input disabled  maxlength="3" size="3" value="208" id="textbox2"  /></label>

<input type="submit" value="Send" />  
<%}%>
```

Here
textCounter() function on keyup event in textbox1 will display value in textbox2,

submit button will submit form which call action "index" on controller "Account",see below how action act

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult index(FormCollection result)
    {
     string TextBoxValue=result["Message"];
     return view("yourviewname");
     }
}
```

please note,above example is solely for MVC project

i hope this example may help you..

Answer (score 0):

> the first textbox has AutoPostBack="true", but when i write in it and
>   click in another part, the page refreshes completely

That is exactly what AutoPostBack is for. If you click on another part, that's when you lose focus on the textbox and it will trigger a postback. If you need more proof then [read this from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx):

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether an automatic postback to
>   the server occurs when the TextBox control loses focus.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i have no problem with the refresh, the problem is that the text i need to update when the event is thrown doesn't change, it doesn't works, simply it refreshres all page and do nothing more.

Comment: "...i have no problem with the refresh...", "...when the event is thrown doesn't change, it doesn't works, simply it refreshres all page..." - I think you are confused at what's happening. Please read my answer again. The reason it is NOT working is because your page is refreshing. Maybe you wanted to do an ajax postback on your textbox.

Comment: Hi von and thanks for reply,
i'm trying this tutorial: http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-use-ontextchanged-event-in.html
It uses the AutoPostBack and change the content in one textbox when the other response to the OnTextChange event, i don't catch whats wrong, it doesn't looks bad

Comment: Here is a video of what is happening, i try the tutorial you send me first: http://remainedesign.com/video/asd.html